# Covariance, contravariance and eliminating superfluous type parameters

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

Given the following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class A {  }
abstract class B {  }
abstract class C {  }
abstract class D<TA, TB, TC>
  where TA : A
  where TB : B
  where TC : C {  }

class E : A {  }
class F : B {  }
class G : C {  }
class H : D<E, F, G> {  }
```

I want to create a simple generic method to instantiate an object of type `D`:

```
void Create<TD>(string description)
  where TD : D
{
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<TD>();
}
```

But the compiler forces the type parameters for `D` to be specified, hence I have to write the following:

```
void Create<TD, TA, TB, TC>(string description)
  where TA : A
  where TB : B
  where TC : C
  where TD : D<TA, TB, TC>
{
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<D>();
}
```

Which means that instead of being able to write

```
Create<H>("foo");
```

I have to write

```
Create<H, E, F, G>("foo");
```

My question is: since I'm specifying `H` as the concrete instance, why does the compiler require the additional type parameters for the base class `D` on the method signature? Why can't it simply infer those from `H`?

Comment: Would you expect to be able to say `where TL : List` to mean "`TL` is some closed `List<>`, but I don't care which" ?

Answer (score 2):

`where TD : D` implies D is not generic, where as where where `TD : D<TA, TB, TC>` implies that D is generic.